# Azure API Management - Validate-JWT - disable certificate validation

Tags: ssl, certificate, jwt, azure-api-management

Is there anyone with experience in using Azure API Management, and in particular with validating JWT tokens sent to it using the policy model?

I've configured the `<validate-jwt>` tag properly, but my tokens are signed asymmetrically so I need to use the `<openid-config>` tag to let the system know where to get the public key.

And in doing so, the system will call to that url over SSL/TLS, but in my case the host is configure to offer SSL/TLS with a self-signed certificate.

Is there any way to disable this? I know the official docs mention disabling certificate validation when it comes to calling the backend APIs, but this is a front-facing API. And setting that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried abusing the declarative model of the policies, to somehow run C# code that disables that, but to no avail.

Does anyone know any other way of doing this? Either disabling the validation, or forcing trust with the self-signed certificate.

Thank you, and have a good one.

EDIT: This is how my configuration looks like:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="https" require-signed-tokens="true">
     <openid-config url="https://identityserverhost/.well-known/openid-configuration" />  
     <audiences>
          <audience>audience</audience>
     </audiences>
     <issuers>
          <issuer>issuer</issuer>
     </issuers>
</validate-jwt>
```

The https://identityserverhost is served over https, but with a self-signed certificate, if this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible at the moment, would be a good feature though. You could switch to http instead of https in openid-config, if you're comfortable with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think getting a properly signed certificate seems to be the best option for me currently.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the certificate you can load it on API Management
and validate the tokens by means of the following policy

```
<issuer-signing-keys>
    <key certificate-id="my-rsa-cert" />
</issuer-signing-keys>
```